# How to Search PDF Documents for Company Name or Stock Symbol?

Tags: python, regex, pdf, full-text-search

I am trying to find stocks/companies mentioned in a bunch of PDF documents. Sometimes, the company name is used (e.g., American Express), other times, the PDF only contains the stock symbol (e.g., AXP).

I can find the symbols pretty easily with this code:

```
import PyPDF2
import os
import re

tickers = ['AMZN', 'V', 'ETSY', 'AXP', 'AA', 'FB'] 

source_dir = '/Users/person/folder/'
for dir, subdir, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            file = os.path.join(dir, file)
            pdfFileObj = open(file, 'rb')
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
            if pdfReader.isEncrypted:
                print("Skipping " + file)
                pass
            else:
                num_pages = pdfReader.numPages

                count = 0
                text = " "

                while count < num_pages:
                    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
                    count += 1
                    text += pageObj.extractText()

                print("\n" + file)
                # print(text)

                matches = re.findall(regex, text)
                matches = list(dict.fromkeys(matches))
                for match in matches:
                    print("- " + match)
```

But sometimes the PDFs only mention the company name. How would I search for *either* stock ticker *or* company name, and then return both? So desired output would be:

```
/Users/person/folder/file.pdf
- AMZN (Amazon)
- AXP (American Express)
- AA (American Airlines)
- V (Visa)
```

I have a csv file that maps the ticker to the company name, but am open to making this a database or dictionary if it makes it easier.

Here is the sample ticker/company name data:

```
| Ticker | Company Name     |
-----------------------------
|  AMZN  | Amazon Inc       |
-----------------------------
|   V    | Visa Inc.        |
-----------------------------
|  ETSY  | Etsy             |
-----------------------------
|  AXP   | American Express |
----------------------------- 
|  AA   | American Airlines |
----------------------------- 
|  FB    | Facebook         |
-----------------------------
```

And here is some sample text:

```
- Etsy (ETSY): Etsy do eiusmod tempor incid is Duis aute irure Etsy dolor in reprehenderit in volup 
- AXP: Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa AXP deserunt
- AA: American Airlines id est laborum. 
- V: enim ad minim veniam (V) est.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd try to make a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) or `tuple` out of `(ticker, company_name)` and try to match for any of them, and if that returns true, return both of them. Can you suply example data?

Comment: @cripcate just added some sample data

Answer (score 0):

You could find this approach useful:

```
import re

# Create dict from tickers and company
# Can be done from csv file
s = {'AMZN' : 'Amazon Inc.',
'V' : 'Visa Inc.',
'ETSY' : 'Etsy',
'AXP' : 'American Express',
'AA' : 'American Airlines',
'FB' : 'Facebook'}


# Create regex from dict s
regex = ''
for key, item in s.items():
    regex = regex + r'\b' + key + r'|\b' + item + r'|'

# Remove last '|' (or)
regex = regex[:-1]
```

Now your regex will be something like this:

```
regex = '\bAMZN|\bAmazon Inc.|\bV|\bVisa Inc.|   ..etc..   |\bFB|\bFacebook'
```

After the search you can create a dict of tickers found:

```
matches = re.findall(regex, text)

# Create an empty dictionary of matches
matches_d = dict()

for m in matches:
    if m in s.keys():
        matches_d[m] = s[m]
    if m in s.values():
        # Find key from value
        key = list(s.keys())[list(s.values()).index(m)]
        matches_d[key] = s[key]
```

While matches is a list like this:

```
['Etsy', 'ETSY', 'AXP', 'Facebook', 'AA', 'American Airlines', 'V']
```

matches_d (the final dictionary) will be like this:

```
{'ETSY': 'Etsy',
 'AXP': 'American Express',
 'AA': 'American Airlines',
 'V': 'Visa Inc.'}
```